# What is the ouput of this common emitter amplifier?

Tags: common-emitter

I need to know the output of this common emmitter amplifier circuit.

[image: Common Emitter Amplifier Circuit]

I was wondering if anyone knows what the output of this circuit drawing would be I ran this through the Falstad simulator and it's saying AC but I'm new to this stuff and wanted another opinion.

Comment: What does "what is the output" ***mean***?

Comment: This question has just been asked by another guy https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/404242/what-is-the-op-for-this-transistor-schematic-based-on-the-known-values

Comment: Unbiased transistor and extremely high base resistor. Result: Untriggered transistor. So the output will be 15V divided by 4k and 1k: OP = 15 x 4 / 5 = 12V.

Comment: Is that 15V or +5V? I can't really tell.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you describe your input signal?

My guess is, as long as the signal doesn't fall below 0.7V, it might output AC voltage **with an offset** (so you have an AC signal which is not oscillating around 0V).

However, 1Mohm seems a little bit too much for the base resistor. If the input's positive peak is at 5VDC and your transistor's hFE=100, you'll have less than half a milliamp on the collector. Since you have a voltage divider on the collector drawing 1mA, you'll have a small output signal compared to the input.

If you're willing to amplify an AC signal, I suggest you take a look at the common emitter amplifier ([here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amp_2.html)). It works like your circuit, but adds capacitive decoupling to the input and output (so you can have AC without offset). It also adds emitter and base resistors for polarization and an emitter capacitor to increase AC gain.