# Resistor network - how do I reduce this?

Tags: resistors, resistance, parallel, series

[image]

How do I find the value of this resistor network. Is the 10 ohm resistor in parallel with the 20 ohm resistor? Is the 16 ohm resistor in parallel with the 5 and 20 ohm resistors in series?

I can't work out what is in series and what is in parallel. I would really appreciate some help. Thank you.

Comment: There are small gaps all over your digram and the vertical red-line does not appear to be consistent with your hand drawn connections. Your circuit is unclear and so is your question.

Comment: Really?  I think both are perfectly clear.  They are inexperienced, but why else would he be here?

Comment: @Andyaka The vertical red line is a very common element of paper pre-printed with lines in my part of the world; it's reasonably clear (at least to me) that there is no intent to consider it a part of the circuit.

Comment: @Andrey - Hi, Regarding your (now deleted) question about homework answering policy, I recommend reading the moderator comment on [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/404229/what-is-the-ouput-of-this-common-emitter-amplifier#comment994698_404229) as an example, and also the Meta topic link which it contains. Hope that helps.

Comment: You have 10 ohm in series with (a 20 ohm in parallel with a (6 + 15 ohm)).  Roughly: 20 in parallel with 21 is around 10, and in series with another 10 will be around 20, which JAS823 shows the math for below.

Comment: Thank you all very much, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next step you have to learn is the ability to extract information from you schematics and re-arrange things to quickly seen what is connected to what, which one is in parallel or in series.

Look at this. And after that, you have to make exercise again and again, until you'll see things !

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for putting in so much effort to help. I really appreciate it. I know I need to work on recognising this

Comment: You'r welcome ;-)

Answer (score 6):

This looks like a homework exercise and at this site we strongly consider not providing full answers to questions of this nature. So all I will provide is a starting hint.

Any current flowing through the 5 ohm resistor has to be the same as the current flowing through the 16 ohm resistor.

Comment: plus 1 for the gentle approach

Comment: Thank you for this. Your comment helped me to work it out myself and redraw the circuit in a new way, from this I think I was able to work out the rest. I appreciate your help very much

Answer (score 1):

The first step you'll have to do at such an exercise is usually to redraw your scheme. Just move the resistors until they are arranged in a more "logical" way.
I hope this helps.

When doing this, keep in mind that as long as you move the resistors along the lines they are connected to, you're not changing the circuit at all.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDzLRv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>